# Win32 app crash on Windows Embedded 8 Pro

Tags: winapi, windows-8, crash, x86

Here is the situation:
App: C#    Platform: X86 
DLL: C++   Platform: WIN32

**Test1:**
(Rugged Tablet PC) with: Windows Embedded 8 Pro
32-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

The app runs fine, but the call to the DLL crash.

**Test2:**
(Rugged Tablet PC) with: Windows 8 Pro
32-bit Operating System, x86-based processor

All OK! App and call to DLL are fine.

Thank you for helping me to figure what is going on. What is it crashing in Test1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Embedded is customized to not include all the features that the full version has.  This means less stuff running in the background, and less files that may need security updates.

But it also means if you try to use those features you will fail.  The exception message should give you information about what was missing.  I suggest that you log the exception information, to help you troubleshoot or work around the issue.

The included set of features is fully customizable, so you will need to contact whoever you got the tablet from in order to determine everything that is missing.

Comment: This is the message I get when it crash, it is not very useful.     A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @vcd: Did you check for inner exceptions?